# Nginx Docker, Nginx connect() to unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket failed

Tags: python, linux, docker, nginx

I'm trying to execute python scripts trough fcgiwrap.socket on my Nginx server.

I wrote a Dockerfile that builds Nginx server from Nginx source code and starting nginx process. I keep getting the same error **`2022/03/10 09:53:36 [error] 10#0: *7 connect() to unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting  to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /test.py HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:",`** when trying to execute test.py script after starting Nginx Docker container.

Could anyone give me some help please?

- Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.10-bullseye

# nginx, nginx upload module version
ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.20.2
ENV UPLOAD_MODULE_VERSION 2.3.0

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gcc g++ make \
    && apt-get install -y fcgiwrap zlib1g zlib1g-dev openssl libssl-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev

# create nginx user/group and add nginx user to nginx group
RUN addgroup --system --gid 102 nginx \
    && adduser --system --disabled-login --ingroup nginx --no-create-home --home /nonexistent --gecos "nginx user" --shell /bin/false --uid 102 nginx

# compile and build nginx with nginx upload module
RUN set -x \
    && wget -P /usr/src "https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-upload-module/archive/${UPLOAD_MODULE_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
    && tar -xzvf /usr/src/$UPLOAD_MODULE_VERSION.tar.gz -C /usr/src \
    && wget -P /usr/src "https://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
    && tar -xzvf /usr/src/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION.tar.gz -C /usr/src \
    && cd /usr/src/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION \
    && CONFIG="\
    --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin/nginx \
    --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    --pid-path=/var/run/nginx/nginx.pid \
    --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx/nginx.lock \
    --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
    --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
    --user=nginx \
    --group=nginx \
    --with-debug \
    --with-compat \
    --add-module=/usr/src/nginx-upload-module-${UPLOAD_MODULE_VERSION} \
    " \
    && ./configure $CONFIG \
    && make -j $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) \
    && make install \
    && mkdir /var/lock/nginx 

# set up upload directory
ENV UPLOAD_FOLDER /upload
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/conf.d/ \
    && chown nginx:nginx -R /etc/nginx/conf.d \
    && mkdir /usr/local/nginx/scripts/ \
    && chown nginx:nginx -R /usr/local/nginx/scripts \
    && mkdir $UPLOAD_FOLDER \
    && chown nginx:nginx -R $UPLOAD_FOLDER

# copy configuration files
COPY config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY config/http.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/http.conf
COPY scripts /usr/local/nginx/scripts

# forward request, error logs to nginx-image-server Docker
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/error.log \
    && mkdir /docker-entrypoint.d

# docker entrypoint
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
# COPY 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh /docker-entrypoint.d
# COPY 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh /docker-entrypoint.d
# COPY 30-tune-worker-processes.sh /docker-entrypoint.d
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# start fcgiwrap process
RUN /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap start -f \
    && chown nginx:nginx -R /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket \
    && chmod 777 /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket

# expose port
EXPOSE 8888

# stopsignal
STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT

# disable nginx daemon mode
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

- checking permissions of `/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket` in Nginx docker container

```
root@3e5ad3eee456:/var/run# ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  4096 Mar 10 09:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  4096 Mar 10 09:49 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root     2 Mar 10 09:49 fcgiwrap.pid
srwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx    0 Mar 10 09:49 fcgiwrap.socket
drwxrwxrwt 1 root  root  4096 Mar 10 08:32 lock
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  4096 Mar 10 09:49 nginx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root  utmp     0 Feb 28 00:00 utmp
```

- nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 8888;
    listen [::]:8888;
    server_name localhost;

    # CGI script path:
    location ~ \.py$ {
        
        gzip off;

        root /usr/local/nginx/scripts; 

        # fastcgi params
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        # fcgiwrap
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;

        # fastcgi configuration
        fastcgi_buffers 256 48k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 48k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}
```

- test.py

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print("Hello, world!")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. The `RUN` statement(RUN /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap start -f ) did not start fcgiwrap process, so the fcgiwrap socket was not spawned.

I added a shell script that starts fcgiwrap process by `spawn-fcgi` command like below.

```
#!/bin/sh
spawn-fcgi -s /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket -M 766 /usr/sbin/fcgiwrap
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this seems to be the missing -M flag in the /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap.sh. By default the start command is doing this

```
Starting FastCGI wrapper: fcgiwrap PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin' /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -P /var/run/fcgiwrap.pid -F '1' -s '/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket' -u 'www-data' -U 'www-data' -g 'www-data' -G 'www-data' -- /usr/sbin/fcgiwrap -f.
```

Small modification to the script to add the -M 766 option and it works.

```
Starting FastCGI wrapper: fcgiwrap PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin' /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -P /var/run/fcgiwrap.pid -F '1' -s '/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket' -M '766' -u 'www-data' -U 'www-data' -g 'www-data' -G 'www-data' -- /usr/sbin/fcgiwrap -f.
```

Without this the socket is created but not read/write for the nginx user. As a result, it fails.

The root cause here is the nginx:nginx user getting access to the socket. So another fix is to change the fcgi_socket_owner/group to nginx.

```
# Socket owner/group (will default to FCGI_USER/FCGI_GROUP if not defined)
#FCGI_SOCKET_OWNER="www-data"
#FCGI_SOCKET_GROUP="www-data"
FCGI_SOCKET_OWNER="nginx"
FCGI_SOCKET_GROUP="nginx"
FCGI_MODE="700"
```

This is a better fix since it allows you to set the mode of the socket more securely to 700.